# Parallell while loops without using threads

Tags: c++, while-loop

(C++)
Is there any possibility to run two parallel while loops without using threads? I have tried putting them one after another, both in one for loop, but it doesn't work for me because the variable that I'm using in while condition is getting changed through 1st loop and I need it to be the same for both loops.
Here's the code:

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < word.length(); j++)
{       
    while (word[j] != tmp->data)
    {
        counter1++;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    while (word[j] != tmp->data)
    {
        counter2++;
        tmp = tmp->previous;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish, as opposed to how you might accomplish it.

Comment: Why not save the original `tmp` before the first inner loop, and use the saved pointer for the second loop?

Comment: Also, considering that you use pointers, you should probably check that `tmp` is not a null pointer before dereferencing it in the loop conditions.

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm getting the letter from a string and trying to find out which path is shorter to get to the same letter in alphabet, going forward or backwards. I am using cyclical doubly linked list.

Comment: If the list is cyclic, and the letter is not in the list, you will have infinite loops.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude One problem at the time, I'm gonna add more conditions later

Comment: And no, there's no way to do it in parallel without using threads. I suggest you use [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) with the `std::launch::async` policy.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks

Comment: You could start another process and set up shared memory as an alternative to threading - but those are your only 2 options if you want them in parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment:

> I'm getting the letter from a string and trying to find out which path is shorter to get to the same letter in alphabet, going forward or backwards. I am using cyclical doubly linked list.

Sounds like you just want one `while` loop with two `tmp` pointers:

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < word.length(); j++)
{       
    while (word[j] != tmp1->data && word[j] != tmp2->data)
    {
        counter++;
        tmp1 = tmp1->next;
        tmp2 = tmp2->previous;
    }       
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work also because if for example tmp1 reachs it's goal first, counter is going to increase more and more before tmp2 reachs it too. But maybe with || insread of && it would work. Thanks

Comment: @niksrb The loop will run until either tmp1 or tmp2 reaches the goal. If tmp1 reaches first, then going forward is the shortest path. It's found the result, so it doesn't need to continue after that. The `while` condition is correct for the problem as given.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible without threads (or you can use interprocess but I guess this is not your point)

You can avoid using "manual" threading though with `std::future` and `std::async`

You can make each search a function like this:

```
int forward(std::string word)
{
  int counter = 0;
  for (size_t j = 0; j < word.length(); j++)
  {       
      while (word[j] != tmp->data)
      {
          counter++;
          tmp = tmp->next;
      }    
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Or the respective `backwards`

And call them like this.

```
std::string word = //....
auto res1 = std::async(std::launch::async, forward,word);
auto res2 = std::async(std::launch::async, forward,word);

//do whatever....

int counter1 = res1.get(); //get the result
int counter2 = res2.get();
```

Note though that `get` will block until the threads are done. But they will run in parallel.

In your case depending on the size of the string/alphabet and the algorithm though I doubt you get much benefit from doing this in multiple threads. The threading overhead can take longer than the whole calculation so you should measure if this may be faster doing this single-threaded.